# How Can I Select A Single Edge Among Linked Duplicates?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges, selection-tools

I duplicated a bunch of cubes to model buildings and I used the linked duplication method, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> but when I tried to select an edge of a cube in *Edit mode* (while in *Edge Selection Mode*), it selects multiple edges at once.

It does not select all of the linked object edges but almost half of the same sided edge is selected. How can I select a single edge of a single object? Deselecting does not work.

Comment: I can't replicate what you mean, can you share your .blend file please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't really know that in linked selection method is it even possible or not!
But I can tell you another way to achieve what you want.
You can use (shift+d) method to duplicate.
Then select all the duplicates and join them as a single object with (ctrl+ J). You can also move them individually in edit mode. But you can't move them separately in object mode,  they are all now one single object. Hope that helps.